# How to create unique random integer?

Tags: database, random, integer, unique

is there any posible way to create unique random integer. I know how to make Array or List with unique numbers, but fact is that I need each time different number cause I am creating something like exam, and I am taking values with different id-s  from db . If I take duplicate number I would make two same questions on exam.

If there is no way to do it, what do you suggest? how to handle problem. I need to generate different id each time from db.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it has to be unique then it cannot be random. You have put one constraint on it from the outset

Comment: Of course it possible, it's just very easy algorithm - remember already generated numbers and when you generate the new one, check if it was generated previously. If it was, generate and check the new one until it's unique. Where is problem with such trivial algorithm?

Comment: how many unique numbers are you creating?

Comment: I need 7/20 unique numbers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you can try something like this.  The code below will give you 14 unique numbers from 0 to 13 and store it in a temp table and you can do whatever you what with it.  tested in sql-server 2008

```
declare @randNumbers table (number int)
declare @rand int, @howMany int
set @howMany = 14

set @rand = Ceiling(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 25)


while ((select COUNT(*) from @randNumbers)<10)
begin

    set @rand = Ceiling(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @howMany)

    BEGIN
       IF NOT EXISTS (select * from @randNumbers
                       WHERE number = @rand)

       BEGIN
           insert into @randNumbers
           values(@rand)

       END
    END

end

select * from @randNumbers
```

Comment: This is the same algorithm as @bSkwared below. I still think it's a bad choice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To create a set of N unique random number from set S, first create a boolean array of size |S| (cardinality of a set, how many elements it contains). Now, each time you generate a random number, check the array to make sure the index of that number is false and set it to true, else pick a different number. Each random number that you generate that had a false index can be added to another array of final numbers.

Comment: I would warn people against this kind of algorithm. It takes extra space, gets slower the further you go, and isn't guaranteed to terminate. (You could get unlucky and keep picking the same number each time.)

Comment: I guess it would be better to initialize the array with 1-N and then choose a random number % arr.length removing each index once found.

Answer (score 1):

If I can restate your question, I think you're looking for "How do I randomly pick *n* numbers out of *m* available numbers?"

In other words, if you have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` as available numbers and you want to pick 4, one possible result would be `[8, 3, 5, 1]`.

There are a few ways to do this. One of the simplest is to put the initial list in random order and then take the top *n* elements.

For example, in Python:

```
>>> available = range(10)
>>> random.shuffle(available)
>>> available[:4]
[5, 8, 6, 9]
```

This algorithm is a little bit wasteful, because it randomizes the *entire* list when you don't really need to.

An improvement would be to, one element at a time, swap that element with a random position after it. This is known as the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It looks like this in pseudo-code:

> ```
> -- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
> for i from 0 to n−2 do
>      j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
>      exchange a[i] and a[j]
> ```

But instead of going through the whole list, only go *n* deep, where *n* is the number of items you need to pick.

Here's a Python implementation:

```
import random

def sample(items, how_many):
    # copy the list
    items = list(items)

    # just do the first how_many items
    for i in range(how_many):
        random_index = random.randrange(i, len(items))

        # swap the items
        items[i], items[random_index] = items[random_index], items[i]

    # return the first how_many
    return items[:how_many]

print(sample(range(10), 4))
```

Many languages/libraries have a built-in way to do this. For example, in Python, the built-in `random.sample` is the equivalent of my code above:

```
>>> random.sample(range(10), 4)
[1, 5, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence in your db and use it to get unique non duplicate auto incremented number... And if you need random number, say something between 0000 and 9999 (just an example), then 
1. Create a method that generates this random number
2. Use an array to store this used number or store in db
3. Next time you generate another number, check if you have already used the number. 
4. Add this whole code in a while loop so that until you don't get a number which is free it will keep generating new ones to check.